# running a js function via onmousedown for newly added ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i'm using JQuery ajax to load new content into the page, on the server side I load a new div:

```
<div id="newFuncDiv" onmousedown="javascript:newFunc("VAR");">Click me</div>
```

In previous cases i used a function as follows:

```
function newFunc(){$("#newFuncDiv").click(function(){alert("something");});}
```

But in this case onclick of this div I need to pass a variable, which I extract from the db on server side, how can i achieve this, as even when I add the newFunc(); with the ajax response it doesn't work,

EDIT:

by the way, forgot to say that i'm looping the response from server so the variable i need to pass is gonna be unique for each div.

Comment: can you clarify what you are trying to do with `VAR` .. it looks like you are trying to pass a value to `newFunc()` but in your function you don't have any args listed nor do you actually use any variable?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Why is your mousedown handler establishing a click handler for the same element? Every time you mouse down, you'll add another click handler, so you'll get multiple alerts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can save your variable into some attribute to each div and assign a same class a to each div like this

```
<div class="clickme" id="youvar1"></div>
<div class="clickme" id="youvar3"></div>
<div class="clickme" id="youvar3"></div>
```

then in jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".clickme").click(function(){
    var uniquevar = $(this).attr('id');
    /*your ajax code here*/
    });

});
```

Hope this help

Comment: @RavinderSingh bcoz this helps other people who are looking for the same solution...

Comment: Since the elements are being added dynamically with AJAX, you need to use `.on` to delegate. Your code will only work for elements that exist when the DOM is first loaded.

Answer (score 1):

since you are using jquery, i'd built the click handler jquery style and attach a data object to the  html element:

```
<div id="newFuncDiv" data-foo="bar">Click me</div>

$("#newFuncDiv").on('click',function(){
    alert("something" + $(this).data('foo'));
});
```

Comment: You need to use the delegation form of `.on()` because the elements are added dynamically.

Comment: didn't i? oh i did! useless comment @Barmar

Comment: No, the delegation form is `$('body').on('click', '#newFuncDiv', function(){...});`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` to reference that div.

```
function newFunc(myVar) {
    $(this).click(function(){
        alert(myVar);
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks first of all, but this still doesn't solve the variable passing problem, by the way edited my question